# USBメモリに入れたUbuntu LIVE USBがクラッシュ。起動ができない上、パーティションも見りません。

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb

USBメモリに入れたUbuntu LIVE USBでクラッシュしてしまったようです。
再起動できない状態です。
起動しようとすると、キャレットが左上に表示されたまま、止まってしまいます。
他のWindowsパソコンにUSBをさすと、「アクセスできません」とエラーが出ます。
Ubuntu Desttopが入っているパソコンに差すと、ユーティリティのディスクアプリからは、/dev/sdbに認識されているようですが、「メディアなし」とオレンジになってしまいます。
コンソールからも試しました。
`fdisk`、`mount`、`dd`、`gparted`、`gddrescue`いずれもディスクを見つけられない状態です。
`lsusb`では

```
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 0930:6544 Toshiba Corp. TransMemory-Mini / Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 Stick
```

と出てきて、USBが認識されているような表示が出ました。USB2.0と、ずいぶん古いものを使っていたわけですね。
`/dev/disk/by-id/`とディレクトリ内を見てみると

```
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-GENERIC_USB_Mass_Storage_0014780DE1B7CEB1E7706517-0:0
```

といった感じで、USB自体は認識されているようです。
パーティションあるいはスーパーブロックが見つからない、状態とでもいいましょうか。

定番の**Testdisk**も試しましたが、USBはリストに表示されませんでした。
knoppixやUBCDでもディスク系、パーティション系のアプリを使ってみたのですが、如何せんディスクを認識しない状態です。
Ease UsやAOMEIなんかもWindowsから使ってみましたが、USB自体を捉えられません。

`gdisk`と`/dev/disk/by-id`を使うと、

```
gdisk /dev/disk/by-id/usb-GENERIC_USB_Mass_Storage_0014780DE1B7CEB1E7706517-0\:0
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5

Problem reading disk in BasicMBRData::ReadMBRData()!
Warning! Read error 22; strange behavior now likely!
Warning! Read error 22; strange behavior now likely!
Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. THIS OPERATION IS POTENTIALLY DESTRUCTIVE! Exit by
typing 'q' if you don't want to convert your MBR partitions
to GPT format!
***************************************************************
```

こんな感じになります。
もし`dd`でバックアップをとれていたら、`MBR`を`GPT`に変えてみるとかしてみたいところなのですが、バックアップしないで行うのはリスクなので避けています。

また、カバーを外して基盤も見てみましたが、ハンダがはがれているとか、ICに損傷があるとかは見受けられません。接点復活剤をかけてみましたが変わらず。

このような状態ではありますが、次の1手があるとしたらどのような方法がありますか？
壊れたパーティションでもいいので見つかれば打つ手はありそうなんですが、、
詳しい方がおられましたらご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: 「何をどうしたい」のかが無いので何をこたえてよいのやら。起動するようにしたい？　認識されればそれでよい？　中のデータを取り出したい？再度 ubuntu をインストールしたい？　その他？　質問本文に追記してもらうと回答が付くかもしれません。

Comment: @774RR さんコメントありがとうございます。パーティションを見つけたいという趣旨だったんですが、わかりづらかったかもしれません。それ以前にここではちょっと題材的に無理っぽいですね…。他の専門的な掲示板をあたりたいと思います。マルチポストにならないように他で投稿しましたらこの投稿を削除いたします。ありがとうございました！